# How do I delete an iCal event without sending notifications?

Tags: ical, exchange

If I try to delete an event on iCal, it offers me these options:

- Cancel
- Delete and Notify

What if I want to delete without notifying?

I'm running iCal 5.0.2 on OS X 10.7.3 using an Exchange account.

*Edit*: Using an Exchange account.

Comment: If you came to this page because you're getting iCal spam, your best option is to block future spam using this technique: http://1wayswim.com/blog/2016/11/23/how-to-stop-icloud-calendar-spam  There isn't much you can do about spam that's already there.

Answer (score 6):

You can move the event to a local calendar. When deleting you will then get the additional option "Delete & do not notify".

Comment: Moving to a local calendar as outlined in Matteos answer has several issues:
a) it's not an option if you're using iCloud (as that'll disallow local calendars)
b) in Mavericks, although the option to "Delete & do not notify", the notification is sent nevertheless!

Comment: @user959380 The answer is from 2013 and it was possible :-) You could have iCloud calendars and local calendars.

Comment: According to the comment above and this thread (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3705591?start=15&tstart=0), moving to a local calendar does give the option to not notify but still sends the notification.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I created a new calendar specifically to move event invites to, which I don't want to see anymore. Then I hide that calendar.

Comment: This is the only working solution. Essentially a "deleted" calendar.

Answer (score 3):

As Feuermurmel says, you can create a new calendar and move it there.  But instead of hiding the new calendar, you can just delete the calendar.  Worked well for me; the event is gone with no notifications.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up doing the following:

- create a new iCloud calendar
- select the invite, and chose the new calendar in the calendar drop down on the info pane on the right
- select and right-click the calendar on the calendars pane on the left and chose delete
- pick the option delete and do not notify

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you use iCloud the Calendar App will not allow you to create local calendars.
The [following answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119813/how-to-set-up-a-local-calendar-while-using-icloud-for-other-calendar-on-maverick) helps.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I wrote a script to do this. It's all at http://thefragens.com/blog/2010/04/dont-send-ical-replies/

The gist of it is the script will automatically alter an AppleScript inside the iCal package. It does not effect the code signing. The script also has a method of reverting itself. You'll likely have to install the changes each time iCal is updated.

NB: It won't work with Exchange accounts.

The zip file has the install bash script, a modified and an unmodified AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting, cut the event and it will be gone:)

Comment: This doesn't work (at least in El Capitan).  It will notify the sender.

Comment: Does not work in Big Sur

Answer (score 0):

If your calendar provider has a web interface, you can instead delete it there. Eg. in Google Calendar you can right click on event and "Mark as Spam".