# Can I have both iCloud and local calendars on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, data-synchronization, ios, calendar

I'd like to share a calendar with my wife that would be visible on our phones. We're both OSX/iOS at the moment, so naturally I set up an iCloud calendar on my iPhone which is visible to her. The only problem is that she does NOT want her contacts, calendars, notes, etc. on the cloud.

While we're fine with setting up Mavericks Calendar.app on her laptop to see both her iTunes synced local calendar AND the iCloud shared calendar, it seems that her iPhone does not support this "hybrid" set of calendars. Specifically, it appears that the only way she would be able to access the iCloud calendar on her phone would be to enable iCloud for iOS calendars which only allows you to merge your local calendars into the cloud; there does not appear to be an option to let you have locally synced calendars alongside iCloud ones. I believe Contacts at least allows you to have a "Merge / **Keep on iPhone** / Cancel" set of options.

I've spent quite a bit of time searching for a solution on this and the closest I've gotten is either:

- set up OSX server or a CalDAV server, which sounds a bit excessive.
- [set up a bogus Exchange account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119813/how-to-set-up-a-local-calendar-while-using-icloud-for-other-calendar-on-maverick), which sounds like it would be local to the phone and won't sync with OSX's Calendar.app via iTunes.

I'm hoping that I haven't missed something in my searches, but everything I've found is either complaining about the missing Calendar/Contacts iTunes sync pre-OSX 10.9.3 when they re-enabled it OR just talking about sync problems in general.

Any ideas?

Comment: fwiw i found the same: its all or nothing. Further: if i sync an icloud calendar to my mac, then do all non-icloud to my phone I am not able to add events to any icloud calendars on my phone. After hours of fiddling it seems like the only solution is to do all via iCloud. Lets see if Yosemite fixes it...