# I want to create a new calendar "on my mac" but the item is missing in calendar.app v. 8

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, calendar

I have migrated to Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite. Sometimes I use an 'on my mac' calendar. I just wanted to create one for one of my projects, but I can only see "Exchange", "google" and "iCloud" but I don't want any of those, just a local one.

The menu item is not there anymore. What setting am I missing?

Comment: Does right click on the sidebar with calendars and choosing "New Calendar" is what You're asking? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I go to "File"->"New Calendar" -> "...".
There used to be an "On my computer" item. but I only see iCloud, Google or exchange there...


In the calendar sidebar there is no "on my mac" section..

Comment: Do You have any calendar under "Other" category? If Yes try selecting it and then right click on sidebar and choose New Calendar. I can create local (on my mac) calendar with this method.

Comment: WOW, yes.. it appeared. And now I also have the menu item under new...

Answer (score 17):

To create local calendar on Yosemite (when no such option is available via **File** menu) navigate to calendar in **Other** section in the sidebar, select one and **right click**, then select **New Calendar**. This should create calendar in **On My Mac** section (local).

Comment: As referenced in [Steve Moser's reply below](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/203219/94024), you may need to hide other calendar groups before this menu item appears. I had to collapse them all then right-click in the gray empty area of the sidebar.

Comment: Don't right click, just select one of the other calendars, once expanded, and then from the menu when you create a calendar it'll become local.

Answer (score 7):

As an addendum to the above, if the **Other** section is not visible in the sidebar, go to **Preferences** and select the **General** icon.

Now select the **Show Birthdays Calendar** or **Show Holidays Calendar** (or both) and close the **Preferences** pane. The **Other** section is now added *below* the **iCloud** section.

You can now right-click in the **Other** section, select **New Calendar** and an *untitled* calendar is created in the **On My Mac** section *above* the **iCloud** section.

I find this very useful if I need an application to run at a specific time each day on one specific Mac and not on any others. This also prevents alerts from appearing on other devices such as iPhone or iPad where they would have no significance.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers didn't work for me until I hid all the other calendar groups by hovering over them to show the hide button. Then I right clicked to create a new calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Just had this problem with a new MacBook running Sierra. I tried disabling iCloud Calendars but as soon as it was enabled my local calendars were moved to iCloud.

Finally was able to do it, by selecting on of the calendars inside Other (i.e. Found in Apps) and then doing File -> New Calendar.

Comment: this simple "trick" works for me

Answer (score 0):

If you first turn off your iCloud account using the System Preferences control panel, an "On My Mac" option appears in the File > New Calendar menu. A new calendar can then be created under a new "On My Mac" group.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to appear by disabling all the calendar accounts in the calendar preferences section, then re-enabling them