# Can I be assured that a calendar on my Mac is not shared?

Tags: macos, calendar, privacy

I use the Calendar application **vigorously**.

In some cases, I link a calendar from my workplace's Microsoft Exchange server. In other cases, I create a new calendar on my Mac.

I have been working under the assumption that a calendar that I create on my Mac is a **local** calendar. My assumption also presumes that a local calendar is stored on the client machine (my Mac) and **not** shared on a network or the Web. (Note that I have iCloud shut off.)

This idea of a local calendar seems like a good way to track details of private medical appointments, illicit liaisons, etc.

I recently noticed that the "Private" checkbox shows up in the event details on my local calendar (with the date, etc). By default the "Private" checkbox is unchecked.

Is my assumption that a calendar on my Mac is local-only incorrect? Will my local calendar events be private, even without checking an extra "Private" checkbox?

Comment: Could you attach a screenshot? Based on everything you're describing, these events should always be private.

Comment: According to Calendar Help under Share calendars > Share calendar events, if a private checkbox appears then the event is stored on a calendar that's in an Exchange/CalDAV server. Can you confirm that the calendar you've created and assigned the event to is in the "Other" or "On my Mac" section of the sidebar

Comment: @Ezekiel , the new calendar in question does seem to be listed underneath the Exchange account. It sounds like you're suggesting that this would mean it is an Exchange calendar. Further to this, if I choose the menu option ```File/New calendar``` it points me only to Exchanges accounts or iCloud. This is a new machine (Ventura 13). Is it possible that Apple has made the misguided step of eliminating local databases for our Calendars?

Comment: The local database hasn't been eliminated, it just seems harder to create calendars in it. If I select a calendar in the "Other" section and then use File > New Calendar it creates it "On My Mac."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a local calendar in the 'On My Mac' account:

- Show the calendar list sidebar (if it's not already visible): `View > Show Calendar List`.
- Expand the 'Other' section in the sidebar, and click on an existing calendar there, such as Birthdays or Siri Suggestions. If the 'Other' section does not exist, select `Calendar > Settings... > General > 'Show Birthday Calendar'`.
  [image: Calendar settings window indicating the location of the 'Show Birthday Calendar' checkbox]
- After an existing calendar has been highlighted in the sidebar, control-click on an empty area in the calendar list, and select `New Calendar`:
  [image: Context menu showing the 'New Calendar' option highlighted]
- A local calendar will be created under a new 'On My Mac' group:
  [image: A local calendar displayed in the sidebar]

This calendar won't be synced or shared online.

See also:

- https://support.apple.com/en-nz/guide/calendar/icl1005/mac
- [I want to create a new calendar "on my mac" but the item is missing in calendar.app v. 8](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161997/i-want-to-create-a-new-calendar-on-my-mac-but-the-item-is-missing-in-calendar)

Comment: Greetings, Kurt. Following your directions exactly as written did NOT work; HOWEVER, they pointed me in the right direction. Even with a calendar in the "Other" section highlighted, the menu option ```File > New Calendar >``` sub-selection had only online options. Using the breadcrumbs you provided, I ```Control-clicked``` in the calendar list, just outside of the other calendar groups. This gave me an option to create a ```New calendar```. Creating a new calendar this way created a new calendar group called "On my Mac", just like you mentioned above.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working via control-clicking! I've updated my answer with your findings, along with more images, thanks for sharing!