# Calendar keeps losing custom event to launch a program. Is this a bug?

Tags: macos, calendar

I had a daily event set up in calendar that runs a particular program.  Recently it stopped running this (possibly after an upgrade?).  Took me a few days or weeks to notice (because it happens automatically).  I go into the event and see no alert is set.

I create a new event and add my custom alert to open a file that is a program:

[image]
[image]

and then when I click back into the event I can see that no alert is present!

[image]

Is this a new bug or am I doing something wrong?

I am on OSX El Capitan 10.11.5 and Calendar Version 8.0 (2092.3).

Answer (score 3):

You are using a calendar that is connected to iCloud. Since iCloud calendars do not support file opening events, it cannot save to iCloud and then it cancels. Make a new LOCAL calendar that is not on iCloud but based on your own computer, then you can do a file based event on the computer based calendar.

Comment: Oh that makes some sense.  But how do I create a local calendar?

Comment: I found out how (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119813/how-to-set-up-a-local-calendar-while-using-icloud-for-other-calendar-on-maverick) but it doesn't help cause as soon as you turn calendar iCloud back on it converts it to iCloud calendar and then drops the custom event. WTF Apple! Get it together.

Comment: @jlarson well funny thing I had this problem not so long ago until I found a forum on the apple website. Maybe I should link it here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5580737?tstart=0  just make a new calendar and select the option local. But apparently that doesn't work for you so I may need to look onto my iCloud settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - couldn't figure out how to create a local calendar, because any I created got moved to the iCloud section. The fix in my case was to go to iCloud preferences, uncheck Calendar syncing, then go back to the Calender app. Now I could create a local (i.e. On My Mac") calendar. Furthermore, this calendar persisted as On My Mac even after I went back to iCloud prefs and turned Calendar syncing back on.

Don't forget to select your newly created On My Mac calendar when you create the event that launches a file!