# Apple Calendar 'Delete and Don't Notify' sends Email anyway

Tags: mail.app, calendar, ical

It seems like Apple Calendar is not honoring the 'Don't Notify' part when deleting a meeting invitation.
Calendar or Mail will sent 'decline' mails anyway when I delete an event even if it is just a 'suggested' event which I haven't accepted before.

###### Motivation

I often get multiple invites to the same event and would like to declutter my calendar or not accept redundant invitations from the start. When I delete events, Mail/Calendar 'spams' the organizer with 'declined' emails which is often quite confusing for them.

###### Steps to reproduce

I am using Ventura 13.3.1 and can reproduce this by creating an event with GMail, inviting my work (exchange) email.

[image]

Apple Calendar marks the event in my work calendar and offers me the 'Delete and Don't Notify' option.

[image]

But when I choose it Apple Mail still sends a 'decline' email

[image]

###### Suggested solutions

I have read about [workarounds](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258468/191568) but since I cannot move invites sent to my work (exchange) email to another calendar they won't work anyway. Furthermore, the 'go offline and then delete the outgoing mail' is not working either since the outgoing email does not show up when my mail account is offline. Most 'solutions' revolve around [spam invitations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/258424/191568) and are also rather dated. The [first comment to this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/82669/191568) suggests that this has been an issue since 2014!

Is there any *convenient* way to deal with this? Is there an Apple Mail/Calendar setting I do not know about? Even if the above mentioned workarounds would work I do not consider them a good user experience.